# Скрыть элементы со сложным id

Tags: jquery, select

Здравствуйте. На сайте организован раздел FAQ.
Вопросы выводятся из базы в цикле и помешаются в div'ы с id=id товара, к которому имеет отношение этот вопрос.
В клиентской части есть фильтр - select c id='product', - который должен скрывать все вопросы из базы, не относящиеся к товару, выбранному в этом списке. Фильтр работает на jQuery. Когда вопрос связан с id **одного** товара, нет ничего проще:

```
$("#product").change(function () {
    var id=$('#product').val();
    $("#"+id).hide();
});
```

Но, бывает, что один вопрос имеет отношение к нескольким товарам. Тогда div'ы с вопросами базы имеют id вида id_poduct1:id_poduct2:_id_poduct3. Нужно скрыть этот вопрос, если id товара совпадает с id_poduct1 или id_poduct2 или id_poduct3. Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: если у `$('#product')` значение 13, то надо скрыть все дивы с id вида 13_productN? 

если так, тогда 

    $('div[id^=' + id + '_product]').hide();

[Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: Не совсем. Если у $('#product') значение 13 надо скрывать дивы, у котрого id, например 13:62:43 или 22:13:15. Т.е. 13 встречается в "сложном" id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Если у $('#product') значение 13 надо скрывать дивы, у котрого id, например 13:62:43 или 22:13:15

решение не особо изменится:

```
$("#product").change(function () {
    var id=$(this).val();        
    $('div[id*=' + id + ']').hide();
});
```

- **[Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Да, работает. Только вот так:
$('div[id*=' + id + ']').hide();
Еще раз большое спасибо!

Comment: чуток затупил, вы правы, испровил

Answer (score 0):

id для этого не очень подходит, попробуйте использовать class или, возможно новые и модные атрибуты data-*, тогда задача значительно упрощается. Ну а первый вариант, который пришел мне в голову - можно поиграться с псевдоклассом :not.

Comment: А как именно предлагаете использовать class? Я тоже думал в эту сторону, но ничего не придумал. Мысли, чтоб отказаться от конструкции вида div id="id1:id2:id3"  тоже были. Но вот чем ее заменить? Про новые и модные атрибуты data-* ничего не слышал. Попробую почитать.